Airflow snowflake connection using private_key_content
I'm trying to connect my airflow dag to my snowflake using private_key_content.
Connection:
{
   conn_type: snowflake,
   host: <snowflake_host>,
   login: <snowflake_user>,
   password: null,
   schema: <snowflake_schema>,
   port: null,
   extra: {
       account: <snowflake_account>,
       database: <snowflake_database>,
       private_key_content: <private_key_content>,
       warehouse: <snowflake_warehouse>,
       role: <snowflake_role>
   }
}

I'm trying to use this snowflake connection to my SnowflakeOperator in my Dags. I'm trying to connect using key pair authentication but it returns an error:
snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 251006: 251006: Password is empty

Have you tried removing the password line from the json instead of passing null?

@SimonP yup already tried to remove it but it still gave me the same error.

you can use an empty string for the password if your key is not encrypted.
If you use an encrypted key (which is recommended) it needs to be the passphrase:
AIRFLOW_CONN_SNOWFLAKE_DEFAULT='{
    "conn_type":"snowflake",
    "login":"<my user>",
    "password":"<my private key passphrase>",
    "schema":"<my schema>",
    "extra":
        {
            "account":"<my account in the format abc12345>",
            "warehouse":"<my warehouse>",
            "database":"<my database>",
            "region":"<my region>",
            "role":"<my role>",
            "authenticator":"snowflake",
            "session_parameters":null,
            "application":"AIRFLOW",
            "private_key_content": "-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----\nXXXXX\nXXXXX\n...=\n=-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
        }
    }'


Cannot we use Unencrypted key for Airflow connection (Snowflake)?? Is it mandatory to you use only encrpyted key ?

@TJaniF Is configuring this connection in the Airflow UI under Connections  possible?

Sorry for the late reply! Yes, you can configure this in the Airflow UI the same way. I walked through how to do that in the UI in this webinar minute 21:30-28:00: https://www.astronomer.io/events/webinars/implementing-reliable-etl-elt-pipelines-with-airflow-and-snowflake-video/
